# Drag and drop files in Quasar

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Does Quasar support Drag and Drop a file to upload like the following?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `q-uploader` supports the drag and drop files.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/BadOwRx

Comment: Can I have drag and drop on q-file ?

Comment: Yes it will work